# Argument is not a function - AngularJS undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and I am currently trying to build something very simple, but I have a problem I am stuck and I don't understand why is it happening.

I have a small project in Webstorm with Express and npm. Angular is added as a dependency, version 1.5.3. I am also using Jade as a template language. Here is what I have in Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/qCR420hBgnlcUisSOwgw?p=preview

Also listed below:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en', ng-app='courses')
head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no')

    script(src='/node_modules/angular/angular.js')
    script(src='/node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.js')
    script(src='/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/app.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/controllers.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/services.js')

    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', ref='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
body(ng-controller='CoursesListController')
    nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
        div.navbar-header
            a.navbar-brand(href='#/courses')=title
    div.container
        div(ng-view)
```

My app.js:

```
angular.module('courses', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/courses', { templateUrl: 'partials/list.html', controller: CoursesListController })
        .when('/course/:courseId', { templateUrl: 'partials/item.html', controller: CourseItemController })
        .when('/new', { templateUrl: 'partials/new.html', controller: CourseCreateController })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/courses' });
}]);
```

My controllers.js

```
function CoursesListController($scope, $routeParams, Course) {
    $scope.courses = Courses.query();
}
```

And my services.js:

```
angular.module('courseServices', ['ngResource']).factory('Course', function 
($resource) {
    return $resource('courses/:courseId', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {courseId: 'courses'}, isArray: true}
    })
});
```

The error I get is:

> angular.js:13294 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CoursesListController' is not a function, got undefined

And I not sure why. Besides, maybe some tips would be useful you think such a structure/separation makes sense?

Comment: Did you forget to register your controller with your module ?

Comment: Is this dupe of _Use `.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {...`_?

Comment: No, it's not that, I fixed the typo.

Comment: I see the function for `CourseListController`, but where are you actually registering it as a module? Also, this: `angular.module('courseServices', ['ngResource'])` is going to create a new app module that makes `courseServices` unavailable in `courses` unless you inject it.

Comment: Definitely, fix that typo in your controller and put the app.js at the bottom of your script loading order.

Comment: @Lex, where do I have to register my controller as a module?

Comment: By the way, there is a whole bunch of things you should also pay attention to, making your controller minification save being one of them (should not be causing this error though)

Comment: @lapadets could you provide a fiddle with your code so we can try stuff to see if it fixes your issue?

Comment: Just created a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107238/argument-is-not-a-function-problem) for this post. Feel free to come by.

Comment: Chat is blocked by our proxy at work, but I'm curious: did moving the app.js to the last script reference resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a loading order issue.

Basically you first load `app.js` which tries to register the function that is not loaded yet.

To fix this just move the `script(src='/javascripts/app.js')` beneath the other includes.

Edit: Alternatively there is a whole bunch of alternatives to prevent such issues like RequireJS, Webpack, Grunt, etc.

Comment: Is this loading order issue specific to the OP's framework implementation? Because I have **always** had my .js script references ordered by app.js, services.js, controllers.js, etc. and it's not an issue. I think, perhaps, there are other things happening here, like the failure to inject `courseServices` into `courses` and the failure to register `CoursesListController` as a controller module (this is probably the one actually causing the specific error referenced by the OP).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it is not necessary to register the controller on the module, you can also define the controller as named or anonymous function.

Comment: Hmm, here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/po53wrkf/) illustrating the issue. Are you saying that the `.controller('MyController', MyController)` is not required (in the JSFiddle)? Because if you leave that commented the JSFiddle example does not work, but if you uncomment that it works. What am I missing?

Comment: In your fiddle you try referencing it by name. If you do that you need it registered on the controller. In OP's example he references the function itself on the router config

Comment: @Aides I gave up and removed my answer, I saw your edit and it's definitely a +1 for you :)